# Does "send" require a "to"?

Tags: verbs, prepositions, ditransitivity

Is the following grammatical?

> Should I send the letter to her?

If it is, then how come that *send* can also be used without *to*?

> Should I send her the letter?

What about the use of *send* in a sentence like "It sent her mad"?

Comment: *Should I send the letter to her?* is grammatically correct.

Comment: You can also change the order of complements: "Should I send her the letter?"

Answer (score 0):

In some languages, the noun denoting the 'recipient' of something is frequently in the dative case.

In English, the 'recipient' can be shown in two ways:

As an indirect object, usually preceding the direct object: *He sent/gave me the letter*;

Following the preposition 'to' following the direct object: *He sent/gave the letter to me*.

Some pronoun/pronoun and pronoun nouns are less commonly used than others.

Acceptable/Common:

*I gave John the letter. I gave the letter to John.*

*I gave him the letter. I gave the letter to him.*

*I gave it to John.*

*I gave it to him.*

Doubtful/Less Common:

*I gave John it.*

*I gave him it.*

Comment: What about a use of *send* in a sentence like "It sent her mad"?

Comment: In that sentence 'her' is not a recipient. 'Send' here has the meaning of 'cause to become'.